# How to close a specific form in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, forceclose

I use this code to close the name Frm_AutoSaleReceipt when I click the button on the other page. But it error like the image.

```
For Each fua As Form In Application.OpenForms
   If fua.Name = "Frm_AutoSaleReceipt" Then
      fua.Close()
   End If
Next
```

[image]

Comment: Error messages are text. Post them as text, formatted appropriately. Also, don't submit your question if the formatting is a mess. Look at the preview first and clean it up before submitting.

Comment: As the error message suggests, you cannot enumerate (a `For Each` loop enumerates) a collection and modify it in the loop. You are enumerating `Application.OpenForms` but closing a form will obviously change that collection. get the item(s) you want first, e.g. into an array, then process them separately.

Comment: Just add  this `Exit For` after `fua.Close()` line as the collections was modified.

Answer (score 0):

Without loop all open forms you can find that in this way:

```
Dim frm As Form = Application.OpenForms.Item("Frm_AutoSaleReceipt")
If frm IsNot Nothing Then frm.Close()
```